# Converting an rgb triple to a quaternion

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, quaternions

I want to convert an `rgb` color triplet to a quaternion `w + x*i + y*j + z*k`.
I thought of it as of rotation, and (using axis-angle representation and Euclidian length of a unit quaternion equals 1) I came to following equation system:
\begin{align*}
    w &= \sqrt(1-(x^2+y^2+z^2))\\
    w &= \cos(\arcsin(r/x))\\
    w &= \cos(\arcsin(g/y))\\
    w &= \cos(\arcsin(b/z)).
\end{align*}

Here $r, g, b$ are constants  and i need to obtain $x, y, z, w$.

I am a bit stumped. On the one hand there are 4 variables and 4 equations. On the other hand... how can I solve this? Could this even be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, $\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$. So you can rewrite your latter three equations as
$$w^2 = 1 - r^2/x^2 = 1-g^2/y^2 = 1-b^2/z^2.$$
Moreover from these equations, observe that if $x = \alpha r$ for some proportionality constant $\alpha$, then you also have that $ y= \alpha g$ and $z = \alpha b$. Substituting into the first equation gives
$$w^2 = 1 - \alpha^2(r^2+g^2+b^2)$$
and from the second equation
$$w^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{\alpha^2}$$
so we have that
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{(r^2+g^2+b^2)^{1/4}}.$$
Plugging this in to the above equations gives you $x,y,z,w$ in terms of $r,g,b$.

Comment: impressive! brilliant) btw, how do you write math syntax? where can i read about this?

Comment: Use latex syntax.  Typing `$x \mapsto 0$` gives $x \mapsto 0$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I've finally managed got working glsl code, due to your effort. I understand, this is not programmers forum, but for those who *eventually* will need this i could post (because i wrecked my head before i got correct result):

```
// converts vec3 color to vec4 quaternion
vec4 c2q( in vec3 c ) {
    c = c / sqrt3; // length(c) must be <= 1.0
    float rr = c.r*c.r;
    float gg = c.g*c.g;
    float bb = c.b*c.b;
    float ww = 1.0 - sqrt(rr+gg+bb);
    float xx = rr/(ww+1.0);
    float yy = gg/(ww+1.0);
    float zz = bb/(ww+1.0);
    return vec4( sqrt( xx ), sqrt( yy ), sqrt( zz ), sqrt( ww ) );
}

// converts vec4 quaternion to vec3 color
vec3 q2c( in vec4 q ) {
    float xx = q.x*q.x;
    float yy = q.y*q.y;
    float zz = q.z*q.z;
    float ww = q.w*q.w;
    float rr = (1.0-ww)*xx;
    float gg = (1.0-ww)*yy;
    float bb = (1.0-ww)*zz;
    vec3 c = vec3( sqrt( rr ), sqrt( gg ), sqrt( bb ) );
    return c * sqrt3; // renormalize
}
```

You could watch [my working demo](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llByRD) of rotation video image along white axis. Feel free to edit and experiment if you like ;-)